# Excel VBA - VLookup not copying data

Tags: vba, excel

I have done my best to read every thread imaginable to rewrite my overall code to get this to work.

Situation: I have data in sheet2 (Scores) and data in sheet3 (Comments).  In each sheet, column A has a ticket number.  The Scores sheet includes every possible ticket number; the Comments sheets only includes a subset of that total (approx 50%).  The Scores sheet includes 4 populated columns while the Comments sheet has 2.  I need the lookup to match the common existing rows (ticket numbers), and then take the value in Comments column B (2) and paste it in Column E (5) of sheet1, which is the CSAT Summary sheet, and has the contents of Col A-D from the Scores sheet.

Below is the current code.  If I remove the VLookup and just put a variable (such as "A"), it does paste A in the correct column, albeit on every single line...

```
scores.UsedRange.Columns.Copy
csatSum.Range("A1").Insert
csatSum.Activate
Set rng = csatSum.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
rngLastRow = Comments.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
For i = 2 To lastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    csatSum.Cells(i, 5) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, Comments.Range(rngLastRow), 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

Not sure what I am missing.  Obviously it is something in the VLookup itself.  But I am at a loss.

Comment: The first argument of VLookup should be a single value. Probably `csatSum.Cells(i, 1)`.

Comment: I think it should be `rngLastRow = Comments.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)`; The second parameter of VLookup should be the lookup table.

Comment: `rngLastRow = Comments.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)` will return an array and as such `Comments.Range(rngLastRow)` will not work.  You need to set that as a range then just call it.

Comment: Your lookup table (even if it were correctly coded) only has a single column, yet you want to return a value from the second column.  Your lookup table should include any columns from which you want to return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
scores.UsedRange.Columns.Copy
csatSum.Range("A1").Insert
'csatSum.Activate
'Set rng = csatSum.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
Set rngLastRow = Comments.Range("A2:B" & lastRow)
For i = 2 To lastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    csatSum.Cells(i, 5) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(csatSum.Cells(i, 1), rngLastRow, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

Comment: `rngLastRow` here is a 2D array (unless lastRow=1) - you cannot pass that to `Range()`  Adding `Set` to the assignment would make it a range (and so it wouldn't need wrapping in Range() )

Comment: OK, I see. Added the Set now.

Comment: Yes! This worked.  Thank you to all for the assistance!